# Can't Install MongoDb driver for php 7.0.8 on Windows 10?

Tags: php, mongodb, windows-10

I am trying to connect mongo db with php but i cant install on my machine .
I got the below error
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoDb\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongoDb\index.php on line 3

I also try to find the Dll file for mongo driver for php 7.0.8 but i cant find the correct file for it.

[image]

Comment: Why do look for 'mysqli', when you need 'mongodb'?

Comment: I was searching mongod and while get the screen-grab i was looking all the drivers are there or not !